# extract information from a scanned form

Tags: java

I have scanned a form and filled it with data by hand, now, I have created the form with javascript and I am trying to read from a pdf in which there are images the data of the text boxes of that image so that they are shown in the boxes of the form created.

I need to create a class using java and read the coordinates of those boxes that are filled in so that they appear in my form but I don't know how to do it.
My browser is google, how can I read the exact coordinates where each box is located and get the information that is inside it?

Answer (score -1):

u can use a combination of JavaScript and a PDF library to extract text and coordinates from the PDF file. A library id suggest for working with PDFs in JavaScript is PDF.js.

```
// Include PDF.js library
import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
// Load PDF file
const url = 'path/to/your/file.pdf';
// Asynchronous function to load & parse the PDF
async function loadPDF(url) {
 const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
 const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
 // Iterate through each page of PDF
 for (let pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pdf.numPages; pageNum++) {
   const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNum);
   // Extract text content from page
   const textContent = await page.getTextContent();
   // Extract info about text boxes & their coordinates
   textContent.items.forEach(item => {
     const { str, transform } = item;
     const [x, y] = transform;
     console.log(`Text: ${str}, Coordinates: (${x}, ${y})`);
     // Now u can use these coordinates to map data to ur form
   });
 }
}
// Call the function with PDF file URL
loadPDF(url);
```

u hv to include the PDF.js library in ur project. If u dont have, u may download it from the PDF.js GitHub repository or use a package manager like npm.

This is just a BASIC example, and depending on the structure of ur PDF and the specific requirements, u may need to adjust the code.

++ Make sure ur PDF is accessible from the domain where ur script is running.